# Is there a reference/archive of English verbs and their argument structure (± their theta roles)?

Tags: discussion, resources

Is there a reference/archive of English verbs and their argument structure?  That is to say, how many and what categories of arguments they  require.  And maybe even their theta roles?  I don't expect there to be a comprehensive archive, but maybe there is a list of the most common verbs.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Good question for ELU.meta, Bernardo. Notice that verbs are versatile. 'Place' for example may, with varied senses, have two arguments ('I can't place him') or be monovalent/intransitive ('Filho placed in the 3:50 at Kempton'). The table above doesn't indicate whether 'arguments 1, 2 & 3' say is claiming that 3 arguments are mandatory for the listed verb or not.

Comment: I just stumbled on https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110892581/html (review: https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/pubs/ai/valencydictionary09.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Though traditional dictionaries aren't particularly reliable for parts of speech, surely with a dictionary that gives examples it should be straightforward to extract the valency and roles from the examples.

However, if you want to -select- those verbs with a given valency/role structure (ie you want to produce a list of verbs that require an object and location), that doesn't exist as far as I know, though it would be a good summer project in computational linguistics to write a program to create that from examples.

That said, I'm sure one could compile such a list by hand for a given language from relevant research articles and language learning resources.

Comment: And if you find or create such a resource please link here!

Comment: Levin's 1993 _English Verb Classes and Alternations_ doesn't give all the information you ask for, but it's easy enough to derive from the information that **is** there.

Comment: Why is this a proper Meta question?  Please do not jump on me. I just don't know. Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie a long time ago it was decided by consensus (I'm not sure if the meta discussion that did it) that resource requests belonged in meta, not main. Maybe resource requests should be ok in main?

Comment: @Mitch Since I can't understand half the Meta stuff and discussions that go on, I really can't say. Thanks, though. I was just wondering. Most of it makes my eyes glaze over. :)

Comment: @Lambie SO is a toy to play with and meta is toy about toys to play with. So it becomes rule play quickly.

Comment: @Mitch Geesus, man, I know what meta means. That is not what I don't get. It's the endless discussions (nha nha nha factor) that go on and on about this or that topic.

Comment: @Lambie Oh... what I meant by "it becomes rule play quickly" is that once you go meta it's meta all the way down and every thing can be commented on even comments and people just like to react, which is easy, rather than think it all through, which is hard, and... and I'm doing the reacting here, aren't I, just extending the conversation by reacting.